# How to design images with three slider

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

want to design a layout with 3 images(https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EkqK.png)mage slider in single fragment class with highlighting the middle slide

i am designing a dashboard screen with 3 sliders in images in android how to achieve this highlighting the middle one

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a viewPager 2, you can attach a transformer to it.

```
private fun setUpTransformer(){
   val transformer = CompositePageTransformer()
   transformer.addTransformer(MarginPageTransformer(40))
   transformer.addTransformer{ page,position ->
      val r = 1 - abs(position)
      page.scaleY = 0.85f + 5 * 0.14f
   }
 viewPager.setPageTransformer(transformer)
}
```

Call this method in the onCreateView of your fragment and make sure that viewPager is initialized before this method is called.